# flutter_local_notification IOSNotificationDetails and DarwinNotificationDetails both not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I'm pretty new to learn flutter and I'm trying to push notification through flutter_local_notifications and firebase_messaging.

My flutter version is `3.3.9`

Here's other pub version:

```
  firebase_core: ^2.4.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.4
  firebase_messaging: ^14.1.4
  http: ^0.13.4
  cloud_firestore: ^4.2.0
```

I've searched that if using flutter_local_notifications version 10 or above, should use DarwinNotificationDetails instead of IOSNotificationDetails. However both of them are NOT working in my case. All relative codes are below.

import flutter_local_notification:

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
```

declare it:

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
```

If I'm using DarwinNotificationDetails, vscode will show error like this:

```
The name 'DarwinNotificationDetails' isn't a class.
Try correcting the name to match an existing class.
```

[DarwinNotificationDetails error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzeb3.png)

If I'm using IOSNotificationDetails, it will show error like below when I try to launch device without debugging.

[IOSNotificationDetails error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UuMs.png)

I've try to run flutter clean and delete pubspec.lock then reinstall all pub but not working. Also try to clean boot or wipe data to android device and still not working.

Please kindly help to let flutter_local_notification working normally.
Thanks a lot.

full code:

```
final android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
final ios = DarwinInitializationSettings();  // get error here
final initSettings = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: ios);
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
  initSettings,
);

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('......message: ${message.notification?.title}--${message.notification?.body}');

  BigTextStyleInformation bigTextStyleInformation = BigTextStyleInformation(
    message.notification!.body.toString(),
    htmlFormatBigText: true,
    contentTitle: message.notification!.title.toString(),
    htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
  );

  AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecitics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'dbfood',
    'dbfood',
    importance: Importance.high,
    styleInformation: bigTextStyleInformation,
    priority: Priority.high,
    playSound: true,
  );

  NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    android: androidPlatformChannelSpecitics,
    iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(),  // also get error here
  );
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0, 
    message.notification?.title, 
    message.notification?.body, 
    platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: message.data['body'],
  );
});
```

Comment: Try removing the const before DarwinNotificationDetails()

Comment: from xcode you need to enable notification

Comment: @Prashant thanks for answering. I tried but still get the same error.

Comment: @Tasnuva Tavasum oshin I'm using vscode develop for now. Any chance I can use it via vscode? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Const variables must be initialized with a `constant` value.
Try changing the initializer to be a `constant` expression.

You have to declare it as `static const` rather than just `const` . `static` , `final` , and `const` mean entirely distinct things in Dart: `static` means a member is available on the `class` itself instead of on `instances` of the `class`. That's all it means, and it isn't used for anything else. `static` modifies members

add `static` keyword before `const` :

```
static const DarwinNotificationDetails()
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I tried to add static but still get error. I updated all my code above so that maybe you can help me figure it out. many thanks!